# Iron-Router dynamic templates in layout like in Flow-Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, flow-router

How can i render dynamic templates via layout in Iron Router?

For example in Flow-Router in layout i can define some dynamic templates:

```
newsRoutes.route('/',{
  action:function(){
    BlazeLayout.render("layout",{top:"digest",left:"post_list",right:"chat"});
  }
});
```

And then i can define another route with another parameters:

```
adminRoutes.route('/',{
  action:function(){
    BlazeLayout.render("admin_layout",{top:"admin_user_list"});
  }
});
```

And Flow-Router will not render nothing in left and right positions.And it is good for me.

But with named {{>yield}} regions in Iron:Router i can't do that. Because Iron:Router save {{>yield}} regions from route to route, and it can be only rewriten by redefined regions. How can i prevent rendering {{>yield}} regions if it not defined in current route?

Comment: Isn't [this section](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-into-regions-with-javascript) relative to question?

Comment: @RamilMuratov Hello! Nope. 
This is what I wrote above.

Iron Router stores information about the region . And is only able to rewrite it from route to route. That is, for each new route will not delete it and re- write information to the regions. It will only rewrite the regions that are explicitly specified in the itinerary . Other regions he left from previous routes.